# Azure VM Server IIS 10 500.19 internal error, tried all the solutions given in previous posts

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, iis

So I developed a `Virtual Machine Server 2016 in Azure`, configured everything by MS documentation and I'm stuck with this error for hours. I have published my code to VM successfully, it works on `localhost`, but it does not seem to work in a `server`. This should be a server problem somewhere and I don't have any more ideas what could it be.

I've been trying everything, reconfiguring, setting permissions, installing apps and features, none of that helped so far.

[Error on server's localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CqH0.png)

Also, this is my web.config file

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E2iH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, editing web.config actually helped. Deleted `anonymous authentication`, `custom errors` and `compilation`. Also it is worth to use https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator/ to validate your config.

Comment: The direct cause of that 500.19 error should be `customErrors` and `compilation`, both are part of `system.web` which you mistakenly used. `anonymousAuthentication` should trigger a different error (locked section).